# GraphLab create installation error: No matching distribution found for graphlab-create>=2.1

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, graphlab, windows64

Unable to install Graphlab create from the link which I got in my mail.
Facing the below issue. Can anybody please help on the below issue?

```
(env) C:\Windows\system32>pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/sinha.dibyojyoti@gmail.com/xxxxxxx/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz

Collecting https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/sinha.dibyojyoti@gmail.com/xxxxx/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
Downloading https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/sinha.dibyojyoti@gmail.com/xxxxx/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
Collecting graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement graphlab-create>=2.1 
(from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to install GraphLab Create in **Python 3** environment instead of **Python 2** environment. Refer to this link --> https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html and read the installation process carefully mentioned in option2.

The best method I found to install GraphLab Create is to create a ***python 2 virtual environment*** using **virtualenv** and then installing via **pip install**.

**Note:** I wouldn't post the product license keys publicly just as a precaution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, I got this error while trying to install graphlab on virtual environment with python 2 version. Not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you post the installation steps that you did to install graphlab?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved. From your conda terminal create a virtual env.. with conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 command. Please make sure you add python=2.7 at the end. Then use the typical graphlab create command with your email and product key.

Note: It's a version compatibility issue.